# How to conditional merge some elements in a list in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I'm building this Builder pattern and I'd like to merge some of the elements in a list together. But I'd like to do this in a cleaner way. This is what I've come up with so far which works but I'm sure there's a better way to do this.

```
function FiltersBuilder() {
  this.filters = [];
};

FiltersBuilder.prototype.addFilter = function(options) {
  var filter = {
    'type': 'selector',
    'dimension': options.dimension,
    'value': options.value
  }
  this.filters.push(filter);
  return this;
}

FiltersBuilder.prototype.addRegexFilter = function(options) {
  var filter = {
    'type': 'regex',
    'dimension': options.dimension,
    'pattern': options.value
  }
  this.filters.push(filter);
  return this;
}

FiltersBuilder.prototype.not = function() {
  var not = {
    'type': 'not'
  };
  this.filters.push(not);
  return this;
}

FiltersBuilder.prototype.getFilters = function() {
  var result = [];
  this.filters.forEach(function each(filter, index, theFilters) {
    if (filter.type === 'not') {
      var filterToMerge = theFilters[index + 1];
      var mergedFilter = _.merge(filter, {field: filterToMerge});
      result.push(mergedFilter);
    } else {
        if(index > 0) {
        notFilter = theFilters[index - 1];
        if(notFilter.type === 'not') {
            return;
        }
      }
      result.push(filter);
    }
  });

  return result;
}

var filterBuilder = new FiltersBuilder();
filterBuilder.addFilter({
  dimension: '_o',
  value: 'origin'
});
filterBuilder.not().addRegexFilter({
  dimension: 'cTy',
  value: 'value'
});

console.log(filterBuilder.getFilters());
```

If `not` method is called before adding filter, I would like to merge the `not` filter with the next element and add that object to the `result` list. But if `not` is not called before adding filter then don't do anything just add the filter to `result` list.

https://jsfiddle.net/9wyqbovu/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of treating `not` as a filter to be added to the list of filters, and processed when you get the filters, treat it as a modifier--a flag. Maintain a `not` property on the `FiltersBuilder` object, initialized to `false`, which a call to `FilterBuilders.not` will toggle. On each filter, also add a `not` property, which is set by the current value of the `not` flag on `FilterBuilders` (which is then reset). In other words:

```
function FiltersBuilder() {
  this.filters = [];
  this.not = false;
};

FiltersBuilder.prototype.addFilter = function(options) {
  var filter = {
    'type': 'selector',
    'dimension': options.dimension,
    'value': options.value,
    not: this.not
  }
  this.not = false;
  this.filters.push(filter);
  return this;
}

FiltersBuilder.prototype.addRegexFilter = function(options) {
  var filter = {
    'type': 'regex',
    'dimension': options.dimension,
    'pattern': options.value,
    not: this.not
  }
  this.not = false;
  this.filters.push(filter);
  return this;
}

FiltersBuilder.prototype.not = function() {
  this.not = !this.not;
}

FiltersBuilder.prototype.getFilters = function() {
  return this.filters;
}

var filterBuilder = new FiltersBuilder();
filterBuilder.addFilter({
  dimension: '_o',
  value: 'origin'
});
filterBuilder.not().addRegexFilter({
  dimension: 'cTy',
  value: 'value'
});

console.log(filterBuilder.getFilters());
```

If you would prefer to be able to say `filterBuilder.not.addFilter` (without the parentheses after `not`), then define `not` as a getter, ie

```
Object.defineProperty(FiltersBuilder.prototype, "not", {
  get: function() {
    this.not = !this.not;
    return this;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, how about if we do iterate it from the right and use `unshift` instead of `push`:

```
getFilters = function(){
    return this.filters.reduceRight(function(results, filter){
        if(filter.type === 'not'){
           //get filter to 'not'
           var notFilter = results[0];
           Object.assign(notFilter, filter); //Or _.merge
        } else {
           results.unshift(filter);
        }
        return results;
    }, []);
}
```

Alternatively, you can use `push` instead of `unshift`, grab the last element of the array as the filter to negate (instead of the first one) and reverse the results.

```
getFilters = function(){
    return this.filters.reduceRight(function(results, filter){
        if(filter.type === 'not'){
           //get filter to 'not'
           var notFilter = results[results.length - 1];
           Object.assign(notFilter, filter); //Or _.merge
        } else {
           results.push(filter);
        }
        return results;
    }, []).reverse();
}
```